# Can we use TFS as Source Code Repository for Salesforce?

Tags: tfs, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

Can we use TFS as Source Code Repository for Salesforce? If yes then is there any TFS/Salesforce API which can be used to fetch the latest code from Salesforce Dev Org?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your code in any SCM system.  Salesforce orgs also have meta-data that affect configuration and this must be exported, usually via an SFDC plug-in to an IDE like eclipse.  Deploying code to SFDC must be through their interfaces and requires test code.  This could all be scripted in .NET / PS via SFDC API, but that is beyond the scope of a post like this IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can fetch the code from Project collection and deploy into Sandbox.
However, the command line fetch from TFS is still evolving and in TFS 2013 , there are some new changes.
[AutoRABIT](http://www.autorabit.com) - a release management suite for Salesforce Applications has support for deployments from Team Foundation Server [ TFS 2013 ] - Salesforce Sandbox or auto-commit from Sandbox to TFS .

- Niranjan